# Angular services: best pratice for observables

Tags: angular, observable

I'm in the process of moving from the basics of Angular to learning more about best practices. I've started trying to adopt a more reactive approach lately, but there is one thing I can't find a good answer to by simply googling.

Now, we can have the following simple method in a service:

```
   public getSomething(): Observable<Something>
   {
      return this._http.get("api path")
   }
```

So, in the calling component, obviously, now we can subscribe and get notified when changes are streamed. But what if there is several parts of the application which should be notified about this change?

So, as an alternative, we could do something like:

```
   private _somethingSubject: Subject<Something> = new Subject<Something>();
   public someThing$: Observable<Something> = this._somethingSubject.asObservable(); 

   public getSomething()
   {
      return this._http.get("api path")
         .subscribe((something) => { this._somethingSubject.next(something) }) 
}
```

Now, any consumer of the service can listen to changes from something$. But of course, you now need to know that there is a connection between the "detached" stream and the method called.

If seems that most tutorials go with the first approach, but is that really reactive programming? What is the best solution?
       }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You second approach is definitely valid for the use case you are describing. In my experience, most tutorials are *either just covering the basics* (i.e. your first approach), or take it one step further than your second approach *by implementing a state management library such as NgRx*.

#### NgRx - State management

Using a **state management library** (*NgRx is probably your best pick, since it's backed up by google folks*) *could* be considered a best practice when building reactive applications.

In essence, the benefit you're getting is a *centralized store of data* that every component or service in the application can subscribe too. Kind of like the scenario you're creating with the `subject` in your service - only for a bigger scope than just one service.

**Why consider NgRx over just shared services?**

**Redux -** What *NgRx* really is, is an Angular implementation of the *Redux pattern*. The Redux pattern, extremely shortly summarized is:

- A centralized store where all your *state* lives
- A centralized place (your *Reducers*) which are responsible for changing the state

  - Your state is *immutable*
  - Your reducer functions can only be triggered by someone *dispatching* so called *actions*

So why are these points any good? Well, when you have a very strict and standardized way of managing the state in your application, debugging becomes *way easier*, since you know that the state could only have been modified in one single place.

Making your application reactive is also much easier, as all of your implementation has access to the same store (you can split the store, but that's another topic).

Here are some really good tutorials on the subject:

- [Managing State in Angular Apps with ngrx/store and ngrx/effects (Part 1)](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/managing-state-in-angular-apps-with-ngrx-store-and-ngrx-effects-part-1-a878addba622)
- [Using NgRx 4 to Manage State in Angular Applications](https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b)
- [Managing State in Angular with ngrx/store](https://auth0.com/blog/managing-state-in-angular-with-ngrx-store/)
- [NgRx on GitHub](https://github.com/ngrx)

Comment: Good answer. But can you name an advantage of using ngrx over using a simple shared service which stores all of the flags that you can use in your app? They are both accessible throughout the app, both singleton, both easy. I'm just curious.

Comment: @echonax - sure, I'll write a few more words on it :)

Comment: Thanks. Knowing that my second example is indeed an acceptable way of doing it was really what I was after.

As far as ngrx goes, I have studied that quite a bit already, but opted out of it for my current project. Even the ngrx devs themselves say that this is not for every project. I find i to be a bit to much ceremony. Reducers, actions, side effect ect ect. There seems to be a lot of code to get the state up an running.

Comment: @echonax - I wrote a few words on NgRx and Redux. Please refer to the links for more info

Comment: @AndreasKorsvoldKristensen - sure, NgRx does come with a lot of boiler plate code which could be verbose for small and not so complex projects. Like you say, it's definitely not for every project. It's good to know about at least, so you can consider it - just like you did. Good luck with your coding! :)